# Changing an span text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an weard problem with an span. I know it should work, but it doesn't... I have read answers to similar questions, but do not work with my example, so here we go: I have a SO simple html with a paragraph wich includes the span, and a button that should change the "doesn't like" for a "really like":

```
<p> I <span id="like-or-not">don't like</span> dogs</p>
<button onclick="changeSpan('really like')">Change!</button>
```

And the function:

```
function changeSpan(someText){
    document.getElementById("like-or-not").innerHtml = someText;
}
```

But it doesn't work... Can you help me, please?

Here ir the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ey50yk6y/

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. It's `innerHTML` not `innerHtml`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ey50yk6y/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are spelling `innerHTML` without the proper casing.

```
function changeSpan(someText){
  document.getElementById("like-or-not").innerHTML = someText;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I clearly explained that it my comment. No need to re-port it as an answer to try and farm rep from it. Vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo instead please.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("like-or-not").textContent = someText;
```